# get value of ajax loaded element

Tags: jquery

I have some code, loaded by AJAX. Like this:

```
<a href="#" class="selectclass" id="seltest" value="1234">Some text</a>
<a href="#" class="selectclass" id="seltest" value="9876">Some text2</a>
```

I want get ID of element,then click.

I try

```
    $(document).on('click', "#seltest", function (e) {
        alert($(e.target).val());
    });
```

but in alert is nothing..

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't repeat ID's in  a page, they are unique by definition , so use class selector instead .

Also `<a>` elements have no `value` so `val()` is useless . Use a data attribute

```js
$(document).on('click', "a.selectclass", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="selectclass" data-value="1234">Some text</a>
<a href="#" class="selectclass" data-value="9876">Some text2</a>
```